# precentage after groupby based on 0 or 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to make a groupby of column 1 to 3, and calculate the percentage, in order to get the result in the result column
ex: if we have 0, 1, 1 => 2/3 = 66.66%

can someone help please

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `groupby().transform()`:

```
df['result'] = df['col3'] * df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col3'].transform('mean')
```